# Why isn't this runnable updating my onDraw?

Tags: java, android

I have the following code:

```
 @Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);
    canvas.drawRect(200, hotCOOL, hotCOOL, 400, mPaint);
}
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
Runnable movePlayer0Runnable = new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        hotCOOL= hotCOOL +20;
        invalidate(); //will trigger the onDraw
        handler.postDelayed(this,5000); //in 5 sec player0 will move again

    }
};
```

The rectangle I made seems like it should be moving, but it's not. Anyone know why this is?

Comment: have you started your handler first time like this `handler.postDelayed(movePlayer0Runnable,0);
`

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the code like this:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);
    canvas.drawRect(200, hotCOOL, hotCOOL, 400, mPaint);
}
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
Runnable movePlayer0Runnable = new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        hotCOOL= hotCOOL +20;
        invalidate(); //will trigger the onDraw
        handler.postDelayed(this,5000); //in 5 sec player0 will move again

    }
};

handler.post(movePlayer0Runnable);
```

Comment: The `handler.postDelayed(movePlayer0Runnable,0);` part has `postDelayed` and `movePlayer0Runnable` parts as errors when I put this code in.